I'm getting escaped characters in template files and output
Im on php 8.3, Drupal 10.3.1. Im getting escaped characters in templates and output, and really no idea why. See screenshot

Advice on correcting this much appreciated

Instead of a screenshot, please paste text and use the quote function; it's easier to read and searchable.  Drupal escapes html as a defensive measure, so you probably have tags that are not allowed by the input filter that you're using.  It's difficult to say though unless you show examples of what templates/text you input that is being (unexpectedly) escaped on output.

@PatrickKenny actually I'll look at the page.html.twig file - I could have made an error there.

Yes, that's possible too. A quick-and-easy test is to switch the site's theme to Olivero (not a subtheme, just the standard Olivero) and see if the error recurs.

@PatrickKenny yes I did that and problem persisted. Eventually narrowed it down to the Lite  Speed cache module.

The Lite Speed Cache module for Drupal was affecting the output. Uninstalling corrected the problem.
